# ITMS-90809 Deprecated API Usage (UIWebView)

Tags: react-native

I'm currently getting the error in the subject line.  I'm currently using RN 0.61.2.  I'm using a bare React Native project but I had to install some expo dependencies in order to implement the "Sign In with Apple" button via expo-apple-authentication  and I think that's what might be causing the issue.

The "Sign In with Apple" button works as expected in my ios emulator but I get an email with this error when I upload the app to App Store Connect.  The following github issue thread is a close match to my issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26255

The following post recommends adding a post_install hook to remove UIWebView and has a lot of upvotes but the path mentioned in the post doesn't exist on my system so this post_install hook doesn't work for me:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26255#issuecomment-528275747

The following post in the github issue thread also has a lot of upvotes:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26255#issuecomment-527447318

However, App Store Connect still returns the same error for the uploaded app after I execute this command.  Any recommendations on what I can try at this point in order to get my app successfully uploaded to App Store Connect?

Comment: executing the command `grep` simply identifies the packages containing `UIWebView`. you will need to uninstall those listed in the output.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615933/7589853. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840722/5954472