# Apple won't accept my app even though I'm not using any UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm having a problem uploading my app to the AppStore. Apple says that I am using a deprecated API, `UIWebView`. But I checked my whole project and there is no `UIWebView`. Has anyone encountered this error? Thanks. Here's apple's message:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more
>   information.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Here's my pods:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '<= 4.8.0'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '<= 5.2.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '<= 4.4.3'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '<= 4.3.0'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'ValidationComponents', '~> 0.3.0'
pod 'Willow', '<= 5.1.0'
pod 'CountryPickerView', '<= 2.2.0'
pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 2.6'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', '<= 3.0.1'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '<= 4.0.1'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.1.0'
pod 'Mixpanel-swift', '~> 2.6.2'
pod 'ServiceSDK/Chat', '<= 218.0.0'
pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '<= 2.9.5'
pod 'DeviceKit'
pod 'SwiftLint', '<= 0.30.1'
pod 'AppCenter', '~> 2.0.1'
```

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries?

Comment: yes. I'll include this to my question. 1 sec

Comment: First, search your Xcode project for “UIWebView”

Comment: Done. I tried searching 'UIWebView' in the whole project, but there's no such keyword. I even removed the word 'UIWebView' in comments. Haha. Just in case. But this apple message still shows. I tried uploading my app 2x.

Comment: One of your pods might be using UIWebView internally. Try to find it and replace with alternative.

Comment: how would i know which library is using uiwebview? I tried this command : grep -r "UIWebView", but it's stuck in "grep: warning: recursive search of stdin".

Comment: I would say remove the versions from your podfile and run the pod install again so they can update. I hope it won't break your code. Try it once.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app ?

Comment: try to use grep -r UIWebView /Path/To/Project/*

Comment: You miss the final dot! The command to execute are: grep -r "UIWebView" .

Comment: ./Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/Versions/A/OneSignal matches
./Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OneSignal.h:/* Web address to launch within the app via a UIWebView */

Comment: does this mean that the OneSignal is the culprit?

Comment: update it and check again

Comment: I've fixed the issue by updating OneSignal version from '>= 2.6.2', '<= 2.9.5' to '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0'. Turns out OneSignal is the culprit. I've figured this by using this command inside the project directory: grep -r "UIWebView" . (including the dot). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WKWebView` is the replacement for `UIWebView`. If you don't have `UIWebView` usage in your code than by executing the below terminal command you can easily get to know that which library is still using `UIWebView` reference (don't miss the . (dot)).

```
grep -r UIWebView /Path/To/Project/*
```

Output for framework match

```
./<ANY>.framework/Headers/ANY.h:#define ANYUseUIWebView ANY_NAME_PASTE(ANY_PREFIX_NAME, ANYUseUIWebView)
```

Output for library match

```
Binary file ./<FRAMEWORK-NAME>.framework/<LIB-FILE>.a matches
```

Update these Libraries

also check out this article https://medium.com/@zivchen_42755/for-me-that-wasnt-enough-it-didn-t-found-all-of-them-thats-weird-something-to-do-with-pod-i-a068d55b7fab