# iOS App rejected after processing. UIWebView issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applet

I am trying to update my app and I am at the test phase.
For that purpose I have a beta test app Target of my App on the App connect and I use Testflight.
That test app is only being used to test the app before submission on different env than the live apps.

But after uploading a build yesterday I got this email:

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, *. Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

The build goes into processing and then disappears.
I checked my plist file.
I checked my app icon

Is the UIWebView the reason for rejection ?
Apple assumes that the app is not yet live so it can't be used with UIWebViews?

Comment: This is an automated process: when you upload a build it is scanned for reference to UIWebView. If the scan finds it then the build is rejected and discarded. You need to find the reference in your code and remove it. The reference could be in a framework or library you have included

Comment: I upload other apps with UIWebView , I get the email , but the app is available even with the warning. Because the deadline is December 2020.

Comment: If the app is already available then you have until December. New apps had until the end of April. Whether it is a new or updated app is determined by the bundle id. Since you are uploading in a different account you must be using a different bundle id and it is therefore a new app.  You can either remove UIWebView (which you are going to have to do anyway) or test using the same account that currently ships the app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562051/1780632

Comment: here is the way to check `uiwebview` in your project

Comment: I know I have a uiwebview in my project. But this is a test app , the main app is already in the app store and uiwebview are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If the app you are trying to upload is not already live on the App Store, you will not be able to upload it to TestFlight if it uses `UIWebView`, period. There is no way around this. By December 2020, even if your app is already live on the App Store, you will no longer be able to upload new versions of it if those new versions use `UIWebView`.

Apple treats all apps going into TestFlight as if they were going to the App Store itself. TestFlight is intended to be used specifically for the purpose of beta testing an application before it goes into production. In fact, in order to generate a public link to your TestFlight build, the app itself needs to go through the review process.

Because of this, I would not recommend using TestFlight as a mechanism to distribute builds of an app that you do not intend to put into production. For distributing your "test app" I would recommend other distribution mechanisms such as [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) or [Microsoft App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/), which don't have these types of restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue before.

I have uploaded my app n got the mail related to UIWebview, so I have coverted the UIWebview to WKWebView and again I uploaded the same. But that time same thing happend again build appear for few minute and just disappears. 
I failed to tackle the problem.

Then I mailed to Apple Developer Support and they replied like Any of the third party library internally using some privacy data you should ask permission for the same.

Then I checked Info.plist, I have given each permission in list still how it comes that we don't understand. Finally then after whole search the one third party library internally using motion related data without permission so this happened. Then I have added that in plist and then again uploaded and its approved.

So please you can check your info.plist and also check whether your third party library using any privacy sensitive data without permission internally or not. May it help you at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project directory and run **grep -r UIWebView .** command. You will get all the UIWebView references in your project including third party PODs/SDK/Libraries.

Replace UIWebView with WKWebView in your code and if any of your third party library internally using UIWebView, ask their support team to provide an update with WKWebView and replace in your code with updated third party library.

You are done! All the best!