# ITMS-90809: UIWebView API Deprecation on Frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, deprecated

Have sent several build without using UIWebView and searched the frameworks that i'm using and still can not find why it throughs me the deprecation warning any suggestions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562051/1780632 ... i hope it will help you

Comment: let me know if it resolve your problem ?

Comment: Tried it with the following on my terminal: 
grep -r UIWebView on directory and still nothing
the project i'm running use ios 9 does this matter ?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: whats the status of your issue ? is it still unresolved ?

Comment: Yes all good tried it again and worked thank you very much! 
grep -r UIWebView project path .

Answer (score 0):

This definitely worked for me:

`grep -r UIWebView project path .`

do not forget the . as it is necessary for the search :)