# Issue ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage in Firebase project (Cordova plugin)

Tags: ios, cordova

My issue is very frequent, but I have some feature. I use Google Firebase in my iOS app. Apple sent me standard warning about using UIWebView APIs:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

My pods are updated.

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Have a communication with Apple and Google support.

Using this recommendation https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729472/10348010 (`grep -r "UIWebView" .`) I checked all UIWebView mentions and sent report to Apple support for checking. Their answer was:

> I’ve examined the output and see two references to UIWebView in there, both relating to Cordova. It appears that one of the Cordova plug-ins that you are using is using a UIWebView, specifically cordova-plugin-browsertab. Unfortunately you’re going to have to contact them to find out how to get an updated version of the plug-in, or what else they recommend that you do.

How to fix Cordova plugins? If it possible to update plugins, how to do it?

Comment: Please add a listing of your cordova plugins (`cordova plugin ls`).

Comment: @BRass the result in Terminal by the project's folder: -bash: cordova: command not found. Or I do something wrong?

Comment: If you are running a cordova project, and you don't have the Cordova CLI installed, you likely have much bigger problems.

Comment: No, I builded my project using Xcode and Firebase SDKs only. I did't use any Cordova stuff. That's the point

Comment: Then, unfortunately, I would say the Apple support person who referenced Cordova problems is leading you down the wrong path, hunting for something that isn't relevant in your project.