# After removing UIWebView, Same error coming from App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, app-store, deprecation-warning

I have an app live on Appstore since 3-4 years, for feature enhancement I have done some changes & trying to upload on Appstore. I receive email of UIWebView deprication.

After that I have commented code which contains UIWebView. Then after I tried to upload but got same error email. Invalid binary and same reason.

Then again I have removed all code which contains UIWebView also I have removed all references from Storyboard as well. But this time I am getting same error email from Apple.

I have also tried by removing derived data. but facing same issue.

What's wrong with Apple???

Can't they specify class or module where they find it??

[image: Email from Apple]

Looking for quick help.

NOTE: App language is Objective-C

XCode version - 11.3.1

Min iOS Support - iOS 9

Comment: update your Xcode and build again.

Comment: Dose any Framework responsible for this error?

Comment: can you list out all the frameworks and 3rd party libraries you use?

Comment: I have twitterKit, FBSdk & Intercom. To get it's latest frameworksI have to add pods for same. But even after adding latest versions of all 3. I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

They can find UIWebView in Dependencies.

Try to check in libraries and update their if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of your dependencies. There's a few options here to find out which one [ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage -- Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app)

Comment: My project is not having any pod