# App Store Connect ITMS-90809 error: Native iOS app developed with Cordova using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, app-store-connect, native

We are developing a native iOS app using Cordova and its plugins. We installed Cordova using CocoaPods.

The app is working fine in the simulators and real devices. But when we are uploading it to App Store Connect we are getting the following error:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage – Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs.

For the above issue we installed `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` with CocoaPods. It is working fine in simulators but giving the same error during the upload.

So kindly help us to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage -- Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app)

Comment: It is an Native app. I installed cordova via cocoapods. By predefined in cordova there is UIWebview. My question is how can i disable the UIWebview during the app store upload.

My Pod file,

Comment: My pod file

pod 'Cordova', '5.1.1'
pod 'cordova-plugin-network-information'
pod 'cordova-plugin-device'
pod 'cordova-plugin-statusbar'
pod 'cordova-plugin-file'
pod 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the following in your config.xml in the iOS platform element?

```
 <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
 </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in config.xml under `<platform name="ios">`

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

And make sure you're using [Cordova iOS 5.1.1](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/12/02/cordova-ios-release-5.1.1.html) or later