# New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios

I have uploaded a build on App Store and after sometime I got an email that

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).**

and I have checked that I am not using UIWebView but I am using **Facebook** and **Gmail** sign in and I have successfully updated Facebook pod file but unable to update google pod file to the latest version. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app

Comment: In your frameworks -- ```grep -r UIWebView```

Comment: maybe you are not use but in your project have this UIWebView so just search all project and if you are not use then delete file if you get in pod also remember dont delete pod only delete UIWebView file only in perticular find pod

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage -- Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app)

Comment: @kthorat I have used grep -r UIWebView command and it is showing ./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,
and I have updated pod for google sign in but it is not updating to latest version i.e. 5.x

Comment: What issue are you having in updating the Google pod? Can you update the question showing that part of your `Podfile` please?